Translating a motto (you can't always please everyone, but you can always save money)
I'm just looking for some feedback and advice in translating a whimsical family motto: you can't always please everyone, but you can always save money.
The literal translation isn't very punchy:

Quamquam semper omnis placere non potes, tamen semper pecuniam parcere potes.

I was wondering if it's possible to use shorter connectives:

Si semper omnis placere non possis, sed semper pecuniam parcere potes.

Is it possible to elide one verb and have it share the infinitives? (I'm guessing not)

Si omnis placere non, sed semper pecuniam parcere potes.

Or perhaps use an imperative:

Omnis placere non potes; pecuniam parce.

I appreciate any thoughts.

omnibus placere saepe non licet, sed pecuniam parcere semper decet/potes ?

Your first version seems like the logical way to go to me, even though it is not very pithy. You would have to change the meaning to make it more pithy.

You have already suggested several patterns. But for feedback:

placere does not work with the accusative, but with the dative. hence we should use omnibus placere.

parcere does not usually work with accusative. in Lewis & Short dictionary this usage is marked as ante-classical. Actually, the example they cite for this usage is pecuniam (Plaut. Curc. 3, 11; which I can't find the quote for some reason: to see what it actually means in the context. It can mean to use money sparely which is little different from "save" money ). I believe there are better alternatives than parcere pecuniam or even parcere pecuniae - I'll revisit this section if I find a nice one.


To shorten, we can find alternative for "non semper" like raro. then we can have something like: raro potes omnibus placere, sed semper pecuniam servare. to use one potes is fine, and I think it is better when they are in the same direction (i.e., without non). Perhaps it is even better without the sed: raro ombinus palcere, semper pecuniam servare potest
Not sure if the following pattern works for you but it worth considering (note the usage of future imperative which is not uncommon in mottos):
Proximus esto bonis, si non potes optimus esse. (Distiches of Cato)
